# Sharing Interface between different processes

Tags: c#, interface, share

Currently I am working on a problem which is implemented as a combination of different modules. Each module is written in C# and is supposed to run as separate Process. I have an Interface **I**, and a class, Let's call it X, which implements this **I**. This class encapsulates information that is required by all the modules.

Now what would be the best way to go about implementing it. Is there a novel way of Sharing this interface between different modules?

EDIT:
Each module kicks of at different time.
M1 (t1) ---> x instances of M2 (time t2) ---->...

Let's say we have an interface **Machine** and an Implementation **VirtualMachine**. Currently each module define their own Interface and class. Before dying, the module write the object to storage and the next module, right after coming to life, forms the object in memory from stored information. I am looking for a way where I don't have to redefine the Interface in each Module.

Comment: A novel way? What way are you doing it now? Why is it an issue? What novel thing are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have edited the question to add some more info. Hope this Helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can use WCF service. You will have your interface as service contract and thus can your interface not only between to processes, but between machines. If you need only processes use NamedPipe binding.